# How to remove the circle in the background of the impress.js demo

Tags: css, impress.js

I just checked out the impress.js demo and it seems to be a powerful tool.
I am not very experienced with CSS, and i would like to use the attached CSS as a template.

But there is a yellow circle / ellipse in the background of the presentation and i cannot figure out which part of the CSS is responsible for that.

So how can I remove / modify this background figure?

**EDIT (Solved)**

I tried to append a screenshot. But when uploading, the screenshot did not contain the yellow circle. 
It turned out to be a problem with my secondary screen. On the primary screen it looks perfect.

Seems to be some problem with my video driver / screen hardware.

Sorry guys!

Comment: please add some snapshots to illustrate the issue, and some code snippets off of areas you think are problematic. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you are referring to the "spotlight" in the center, it's generated be the CSS gradient applied to the document `body`:

```css
body {
    /* ... */
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, 50% 50%, 0, 50% 50%, 500, from(#F0F0F0), to(#BEBEBE));
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(#F0F0F0, #BEBEBE);
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(#F0F0F0, #BEBEBE);
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(#F0F0F0, #BEBEBE);
    background: -o-radial-gradient(#F0F0F0, #BEBEBE);
    background: radial-gradient(#F0F0F0, #BEBEBE);
}
```

omit these rules, and you're good to go.

**References:**

- [Using CSS gradients on Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_gradients)
- [examples on CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/examples/CSS3Gradient/)
- [CSS-Tricks article on the performance-wise profitability of using CSS gradients over images](http://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/)
- [a photoshop-like CSS gradient generator on ColorZilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

Comment: Well i do want to have a gradient, but without the yellow circle. When I generate a gradient here http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/graphics/cssgradientbackgroundmaker/default.html it looks fine but when pasting the generated code the yellow circle is back...

Comment: i've no idea now what's the yellow circle. please post a snapshot in you question. thanks.

Comment: please share your answer so others may benefit from it.